# Am I allowed to use the loading gif from facebook in my own software?

Tags: software-distribution

I would like to know if I'm allowed to use a small image like the loading gif from facebook, 
or maybe if I remake it and do something that looks exactly the same

Can I use it in my own software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the gif is on the Facebook servers then you should assume that they own the copyright and have exclusive use of it unless there is a license somewhere that says otherwise.

There are plenty of free (not encumbered by copyright, or under a free license) spinners available on the net, and even [a site](http://www.ajaxload.info/) the generates them for you.

Comment: :) that site has the facebook spinner option